# How can we amplify sound with specific frequency in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, signal-processing

Can someone tell me how we can amplify the sound of specific frequency alone?

Comment: Do you wan to do this in real time? I ask because you may be looking for "Fast Fourier" which requires a fair bit of processor power.

Comment: Jaydee, I wanted it in real time. If you have any idea on FFT, you can give here. I would need that too. Does iPhone's computing powe  power not enough for FFT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to use FFTs for this -- digital filters are very computationally efficient, needing just a few multiplies and adds per sample being processed.

A good resource for the implementation of this is Robert Bristow-Johnson's [Filter Cookbook](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt). There are also good digital signal processing tutorials at Stehpan Bernsee's [DSP Dimension](http://www.dspdimension.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one of many DSP (digital signal processing) techniques or filters, including IIR biquads (commonly used in audio equalizers with minimal CPU/DSP performance capability), FIR filtering by direct convolution, FFT overlap-add/save convolution, etc.